# Showing error when trying to start backup of vms through cli commands

Tags: azure, azure-cli, azure-backup-vault

I wrote the command:

```
az backup protection backup-now --resource-group Rsrgrp \
    --vault-name CLIbkvault --container-name CLIcont \
    --item-name MyItem --retain-until 29-02-2020 \
    --backup-management-type AzureStorage
```

And I'm gettnig this error:

> Item not found. Please provide a valid item_name.

I dont know which item name the error is referring to.

Comment: well, `--item-name`, probably?

Comment: there are no suggestions occuring when i type "--item-name" , so i wrote "MyItem".

Answer (score 0):

My guess this is the first time you try to backup the resource, is that so?

If so, you will need to first add the resource as protected to the backup vault, then the item name will be the name of the resource you are backing up.

Azure VM

```
az backup protection enable-for-vm --policy-name
                                   --vm
                                   [--disk-list-setting {exclude, include}]
                                   [--diskslist]
                                   [--ids]
                                   [--resource-group]
                                   [--subscription]
                                   [--vault-name]
```

Azure File Share

```
az backup protection enable-for-azurefileshare --azure-file-share
                                               --policy-name
                                               --storage-account
                                               [--ids]
                                               [--resource-group]
                                               [--subscription]
                                               [--vault-name]
```

Azure Workload

```
az backup protection enable-for-azurewl --policy-name
                                        --protectable-item-name
                                        --protectable-item-type {HANAInstance, SAPHanaDatabase, SAPHanaSystem, SQLAG, SQLDatabase, SQLInstance}
                                        --server-name
                                        --workload-type {AzureFileShare, MSSQL, SAPHANA, SAPHanaDatabase, SQLDataBase, VM}
                                        [--ids]
                                        [--resource-group]
                                        [--subscription]
                                        [--vault-name]
```

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/protection

Comment: looking at his code he is backing up a storage account container?

Comment: @4c74356b41 true that. But its the same. Just enable-for-azurefileshare in stead

Comment: So is there a way to monitor the backups this way?Also can we restore them?

Comment: @BhaveshDamor for monitoring you use azure monitor for restore you use restore commands https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/backup/restore?view=azure-cli-latest however none of that is relevant to your topic.

Comment: when i am trying to create the backup protection for azure file share i am facing an error saying "'NoneType' object has no attribute 'id'".

Comment: @BhaveshDamor Please update your post with how you are trying to do it and the entire error message.